# HTML created using loops such as map not being rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A custom hook returns data as an array of objects. I want to traverse this array & render a list of its content. While the data is available while traversing, no actual html is rendered on the browser.

This is the react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Conversations = ({ conversations }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {conversations.map((conversation, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{conversation.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

Conversations.propTypes = {
  conversations: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      last_seen_at: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })
  ).isRequired,
};

export default Conversations;
```

This is the array being passed as conversations :

```
const conversationsData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'ali',
    last_seen_at: '2023-08-21T18:55:14.000000Z',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'andre',
    last_seen_at: '2023-08-21T13:37:53.000000Z',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'bram',
    last_seen_at: '2023-07-21T22:00:02.000000Z',
  },
];
```

On the browser, nothing is rendered between the `<ul></ul>`tags.
This application is built on react version 18.2

Comment: How are you passing in `conversations` to your `Conversations` component?

Comment: Where is `Conversations` used?

Comment: Its used in another component. Data is passed as such ```<Conversations conversations={conversationsData } />```. 
Have verified that the correct data is available inside the loop by logging it to the console.

Comment: [This sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76948228-html-created-using-loops-such-as-map-not-being-rendered-5l8s9n?file=/src/App.js) seems to work as expected for me. Is there something else going on with how you're generating this `conversationData` array? You mentioned a custom hook. Can we see how that is used and how the parent component creates this array?

Answer (score -1):

[Write like this from where you pass as props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfPrO.png)

```
<Conversations conversations={conversationsData} />
```

Comment: <Conversations conversations={conversationsData} />

Comment: Data is being passed & is available inside the loop as well. Have logged it in the console to confirm